# Make an addAffair function that will add a new affair on a given date

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Given the structure for storing affairs for years, months, and days:

```
let affairs = {
    2018: {
        11: {
            29: ['дело111', 'дело112', 'дело113'],
            30: ['дело121', 'дело122', 'дело123'],
        },
        12: {
            30: ['дело211', 'дело212', 'дело213'],
            31: ['дело221', 'дело222', 'дело223'],
        },
    },
    2019: {
        12: {
            29: ['дело311', 'дело312', 'дело313'],
            30: ['дело321', 'дело322', 'дело323'],
            31: ['дело331', 'дело332', 'дело333'],
        }
    },
}
```

Make an addAffair function that will add a new affair on a given date.

My wrong solution:

```
addAffair(2020, 10, 21, 'affair111')
console.log(affairs)

function addAffair(year, month, day, affair){
  if(affairs[year]===undefined){
    affairs[year]={}
  }

  if(affairs[year][month]===undefined){
    affairs[month]={}
  }

  if(affairs[year][month][day]===undefined){
    affairs[day]=[]
  }

  affairs[year][month][day].push(affair)

}
```

The result in console is :

TypeError: Cannot read property '21' of undefined
    at addAffair (/script.js:36:26)
    at /script.js:24:1

Please help to find mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating your new object, your are not creating sub object of the year object, for example, All your new object are at the same level :

```
{
    2018: {}
    11: {}
    21: []
}
```

You need to create your new object / array inside the previously created one.

```
addAffair(2020, 10, 21, 'affair111');
console.log(affairs);

function addAffair(year, month, day, affair){
  if(!affairs.hasOwnProperty(year)){
    affairs[year]={};
  }

  if(!affairs[year].hasOwnProperty(month)){
    affairs[year][month]={};
  }

  if(!affairs[year][month].hasOwnProperty(day)){
    affairs[year][month][day]=[];
  }

  affairs[year][month][day].push(affair);

}
```

You could also use `hasOwnProperty` rather than `=== undefined`. It makes your code a little bit more Readably and easy to understand.